# Meaning of function(text) when call Ajax in Javascript

Tags: javascript

I'm totally new to javascript and have difficulty in understanding the meaning of the scripts. :( Hope someone can help me or give some advice, thaks! :)

I have a javascript in which it call Ajax function like:

```
  callAjax('../team.cgi', 'POST', data, function(text)
```

In the ajax2.js it define the function callAjax like:

```
  function callAjax(url, method, data, handler, waittime, timeout_func)
```

My question is what's the parameter function(text)?

Answer (score 3):

`function(text)` is the beginning of the definition of an [anonymous function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anonymous_function). Presumably the call looks something like this:

```
callAjax('../team.cgi', 'POST', data, function(text)
{
    // do something with text
});
```

The function defined between those brackets takes a variable, `text`, and does something with it. This is possible in JavaScript because [functions are first-class citizens](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First-class_function). They can be assigned to variables, defined anonymously, etc.

Typically, you'd say the `handler` parameter of the `callAjax` function is a callback. It's a function that will be passed certain arguments when the Ajax call completes. This is typical of asynchronous code.

The snippet above is functionally the same as this:

```
function doSomethingWhenAjaxCompletes(text) {
    // do something
}

callAjax('../team.cgi', 'POST', data, doSomethingWhenAjaxCompletes);
```

The only difference in the first is that the function isn't defined with the name `doSomethingWhenAjaxCompletes`; it's defined anonymously instead.

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing the context of the `handler` function my guess would be that this is the returned value from the ajax call. For example, if `team.cgi` in your example above returns an xml list of teams then I would expect the `text` parameter in the handler function to be that list.

Answer (score 0):

When issuing AJAX requests, execution does not halt and wait for the response to come back. Instead, the request is send and execution continues. You simply provide what is called a "callback" function which is called when the AJAX response is returned. Typically, the callback function takes a single argument containing the response object or message that was returned as the answer to your AJAX request.

```
callAjax('../team.cgi', 'POST', data, function(text) {
    console.log('Got a response!');
    console.log(text);
}
```

This simply sends the request. At some time later (after a pause due to network latency) you will see the console log message appear, indicating that a response was received and the callback function meant for "handling" the response has been called.